# Show hide image with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 images in separate div

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="morebutton" ><img src="/Images/PLUS.gif" /></a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="morebutton2" ><img src="/Images/MINUS.gif"/></a>
```

Jquery toggle is working fine, But if i open the div at that time **plus.gif** alone should visible, But here  for me both are getting visible.

```
$('.morebutton').live("click", function () {
                $('.more').show();
                $('.morebutton').hide();
            });
            $('.morebutton2').live("click", function () {
                $('.more').hide();
                $('.morebutton').show();
            });
```

Comment: **Note:** `.live()` is deprecated in 1.7 and removed in 1.9 jQuery

Comment: you haven't shown us the `.more` in your html code

Comment: You can use `.on` instead of `.live`

Comment: No need for either here, `click()` will suffice as he isn't delegating anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `toggle()` to display or hide the matched elements. If the element is initially displayed, it will be hidden; if hidden, it will be displayed.

The *el* (short for element) variable matches both classes `.morebutton` and `.morebutton2` as they both begin with "more".

```
$(".morebutton2").hide();
var el = $("a[class^='more']");

$(el).click(function () {
    $(el).toggle();
});
```

<kbd>[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yeeygg4a/)</kbd>

Comment: A little explanation/context would be helpful for posterity.

Comment: @WesleyBland: I agree, explanation added.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this query

```
$('.morebutton').click(function () {
    $('.more').show();
    $(this).hide();
});
$('.morebutton2').click(function () {
    $('.more').hide();
    $('.morebutton').show();
});
```

Probably you wrap your function.

Here is the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/benjaminthomas/p9nks5aj/)

Answer (score 1):

like this?

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aanders50/vvo478k7/)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.morebutton2').hide();

    $('.morebutton').on("click", function () {
        $('.morebutton2').show();
        $('.morebutton').hide();
    });

    $('.morebutton2').on("click", function () {
        $('.morebutton2').hide();
        $('.morebutton').show();
    });
});
```